# How to inject dispatch into functional React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to dispatch an action when an item is clicked within my component. However, I am getting `dispatch is undefined` when the `attendHandler` is fired. How do I properly pass dispatch to a component?

This is my action. I am using thunk, so I'm actually return a dispatch.

```js
export function attendEvent(token) {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  };
  console.log(config);
  return dispatch => axios.post('api/events', config)
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ATTEND EVENT SUCCESSFUL', payload: response.data });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ATTEND EVENT UNSUCCESSFUL', payload: 'Could not attend event' });
  });
}
```

This is my component

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import attendEvent from '../actions/eventActions';
    import check from '../assets/hatch_complete.svg';
    import crossout from '../assets/hatch_multiply.svg';
    
    const Event = (props) => {
      const attendHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(attendEvent({
          token: window.localStorage.getItem('token'),
        }));
      };
      return (
        <div className="event">
          <section className="eventdescription">
            <p>{props.title}</p>
            <p>{props.description}</p>
            <p>{props.date}</p>
            <p>{props.owner}</p>
            <p>{props.attendees}</p>
            <p>{props.capacity}</p>
            <p>Attend / unattend</p>
          </section>
          <section className="attend"><img onClick={attendHandler}className="eventgraphic" src={check} alt="" /></section>
          <section className="unattend"><img className="eventgraphic" src={crossout} alt="" /></section>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default connect(state => ({
      events: state.event.events,
    }))(Event);
```

This is my store, in case it is needed for reference. I do not `mapDispatchToProps`, perhaps that is my problem.

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger()));
```

Comment: as far as i remember you do not need to use mapDispatch. dispatch is always available as props. so instead of dispatch({ ... }), use this.props.dispatch({ ... })

Comment: I have tried that. The error is  `...is not a function`

Comment: whats `...`? can you give me the clear error?

Comment: where exactly did the error point to

Comment: It maps to `attendEvent`. For some reason it is undefined.

Comment: Can you try `export default function attendEvent` instead of `export function attendEvent`

Comment: it should be `props.dispatch({...})`, without `this`

Comment: `export default` worked, yet it was unnecessary for the the other action

Comment: you are importing it the wrong way, `import { attendEvent }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your action as `default` and then call the `dispatch on props` as connect provides dispatch as props.

```
export default function attendEvent(token) {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  };
  console.log(config);
  return dispatch => axios.post('api/events', config)
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ATTEND EVENT SUCCESSFUL', payload: response.data });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ATTEND EVENT UNSUCCESSFUL', payload: 'Could not attend event' });
  });
}


const Event = (props) => {
      const attendHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.dispatch(attendEvent({
          token: window.localStorage.getItem('token'),
        }));
      };
      return (
        <div className="event">
          <section className="eventdescription">
            <p>{props.title}</p>
            <p>{props.description}</p>
            <p>{props.date}</p>
            <p>{props.owner}</p>
            <p>{props.attendees}</p>
            <p>{props.capacity}</p>
            <p>Attend / unattend</p>
          </section>
          <section className="attend"><img onClick={attendHandler}className="eventgraphic" src={check} alt="" /></section>
          <section className="unattend"><img className="eventgraphic" src={crossout} alt="" /></section>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default connect(state => ({
      events: state.event.events,
    }))(Event);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` is available as props, so it can be called with `props.dispatch`